# Creating a slingshot with SpriteKit and Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a shooting mechanism in a simple shooter type game. To put it simply, there's a "line" at the bottom of the screen where the "bullet" lies (think like a bow and arrow), and the player needs to be able to tap and drag the bullet back like a slingshot. The movements I'm needing along the line are left and right along the line, and obviously to be able to drag the bullet down with the line  to create the slingshot effect.

My only theory on how to do this is to create a rope like I've seen other people do with many different segments that are all connected with joints, and then connect the ball to the line with joints as well..but how do I allow the ball to move along the line and interact with each other like a slingshot. Surely the ball would just get tacked onto one of the little segments and not be able to slide around?

Is this something huge and bad or is there a somewhat manageable way to tackle this for someone not super versed in Swift?

Comment: you should probably look at unity it is multiplatform and provides collision detection

Comment: @johnny5 This question is about SpriteKit that does provides collision detection as well. This page is not the place to sponsor other game engines.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a rope with the bullet attached to the end (have the bullet's location be the end of the rope):

```
let rope = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rope")
rope.position = //location at bottom of screen
rope.size = //size that looks good resting
rope.name = "restingRope"
rope.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
self.addChild(restingRope)
```

Then, when the user presses and drags the bullet, remove that rope, create a new rope whose length is from the origin of "rope" (the original rope) to wherever the user has their finger according to the `touchesMoved` function. Then move the bullet to the end of the new rope and change its position by using the `SKAction.moveBy(x: , y: , duration: )` function. Don't forget to remove the old rope.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        childNodeWithName("restingRope")?.removeFromParent()//remove origional rope
        var nodeTouched = SKNode()
        var currentNodeTouched = SKNode()


        let rope = childNodeWithName("rope") //reference old rope

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            childNodeWithName("strechedRope")?.removeFromParent() //remove strechedRope (will do nothing if it has not been initialized)

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var strechedRope = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rope")
            strechedRope.position = rope!.position
            strechedRope.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
            strechedRope.size = CGSizeMake(location.x - rope!.position.x, 5)
            strechedRope.name = "strechedRope"
            self.addChild(strechedRope)
        }
    }
```

When the user lets go (`touchesEnded`), apply an impulse to the bullet and move the rope with it. I did not include any of the bullet code because it seems self explanatory. If not, let me know.

Hope this helped and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this, hopefully this fits your expectations.  This is mostly for 2d but could work in 3d.  Your slingshot should be made out of three things.

1. One line
2. Another line
3. Slingshot sprite
4. Bullet

Then what you do from their is sorta simple.  I would write out the code, but I don't exactly know how to draw a line between two moving points.  But basically what you would do is draw line 1 from the slingshot to the bullet, and line2 from the slingshot to the bullet.  Then make the bullet draggable, and then when it is released get the vector from the dragged position, to the original bullet position, and apply it as a physics impulse.  This should work.